# 'break' and 'continue' are only allowed inside a loop - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, break

marked line with stars codes fail in a case in the When loop.

Error Description : 'break' and 'continue' are only allowed inside a loop.

Please help me, thank

How do I implement a solution?

```
if (mOpenedItems.size == 0) break //*****************ERROR************
// Disallow our parent Views to intercept the touch events so long as there is

// at least one item view in the open or being closed state.
requestParentDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()
if (mFullyOpenedItem != null) {
    mHasItemFullyOpenOnActionDown = true
    if (mActiveItem === mFullyOpenedItem) {
        resolveActiveItemMenuBounds()
        // If the user's finger downs on the completely opened itemView's menu area,
        // do not intercept the subsequent touch events (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP, etc.)
        // as we receive the ACTION_DOWN event.
        // If the user's finger downs on the fully opened itemView but not on
        // its menu, then we need to intercept them.
        if (mActiveItemMenuBounds.contains(mDownX, mDownY)) {
            break //**************************ERROR***************
        } else if (mActiveItemBounds.contains(mDownX, mDownY)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    // If 1) the fully opened itemView is not the current one or 2) the user's
    // finger downs outside of the area in which this view displays the itemViews,
    // make the itemView's menu hidden and intercept the subsequent touch events.
    releaseItemViewInternal(mFullyOpenedItem, itemScrollDuration)
}
```

Comment: `when` is not a loop

Comment: It might be helpful to add a little more of the surrounding code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided there are no loops to break out of hence the error.

`break;` only works within `while` `do while` and `for` loops and it causes your program to drop out of the bottom of the loop without executing any further code within it.

Going by what I think your trying to do, you should replace your breaks with `return false`. Though I could very easily be wrong because the sample you have provided is not a complete function.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_break_statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

But what would you like to break?
If statement, method, whole process?

Both, `continiue` and `break` statements are created to be used in loops.
`break` statement is used to exit from a loop (no more courses).
`continue` statement is also used in loops to process next loop course.

If you want finish from whole method intermediately use `return <value>`.
You can also throw an exception (and handle it in other frame) -> `throw Exception("msg")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no existence of any loop in your code, hence, there is no point in adding `break` or `continue`. You only have conditional statements like `if` and `else if` in your code but not loops like `for`, `while`, `do while` etc. in your code. `break` and `continue` only work in loops.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is solved.

```
when (e.action) {
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> run {
```

and

```
if (mOpenedItems.size == 0) return@run
```